# SQL SELECT Statement - Multiple IDs in IN Clause

Tags: sql, sql-injection, in-clause

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Every now and then I work on a system that allows the user to select multiple items and then perform a bulk action on them. Typically, I resorted to building the SQL at runtime, something like this:

```
string inClause = String.Join(", ", selectedIds);
string command = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId IN ({0})";
command = String.Format(command, inClause);
```

Of course, this style of code is insecure because of SQL injection. I could solve that by putting in parameter placeholders and creating parameters.

Still, I am wondering if there is another approach that I've just not considered. I certainly don't want to execute the command once for each ID.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/284240

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause

Comment: If `selectedIds` is an array of integers, there's no danger of SQL injection.  There's no way to stuff an `'` in an integer.

Comment: it is safe as long as you verify that they are integers.

Answer (score 1):

There are two good approaches:

1. Build the string with command placeholders (like you said)
2. Join to the values of a TVP

Burning the IDs into the SQL is not good because it prevents plan caching and opens the potential for injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an XML string and then pass it to a stored proc.  Executing it would look like:

```
EXECUTE getLocationTypes '<IDList><ID>1</ID><ID>3</ID></IDList>'
```

The stored proc would look something like:

```
create proc [dbo].[getLocationTypes](@locationIds XML)
as  
begin  
set nocount on  

SELECT locationId, typeId
FROM xrefLocationTypes 
WHERE locationId 
IN (SELECT Item.value('.', 'int' )
FROM @locationIDs.nodes('IDList/ID') AS x(Item))
ORDER BY 1, 2

end
```

Notice the data type of the parameter is XML. This is a little more complicated than what you are doing, guess you could do it all in a single SQL string.